# How to update an element in a list with a reactive input?

Tags: shiny, reactive-programming

I have a list object that I would like to update with a reactive input. The object has to be a list.

Below is my minimal code. Thanks in advance.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      numericInput("number", "Change number", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
      verbatimTextOutput('show')
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    QG <- list(a = c(1:10),
           b = LETTERS[1:10])


    #How to update reactiveVal from reactive input
    #QG$a[2] <- input$number

    output$show <- renderPrint({
      QG$a[2]
    })

  }

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
library(shiny)

QG <- list(a = c(1:10),b = LETTERS[1:10])

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      numericInput("number", "Change number", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
      verbatimTextOutput('show')
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    Values <- reactive({
      QG$a[2] <- as.numeric(input$number)
      QG
    })
    output$show <- renderPrint({
      Values()
    })
  }
)
```